# Is there any equivalent function for taking hours using Date Part in spark sql

Tags: apache-spark

I was trying to do DatePart  date function in SQL. But i am trying to convert in to Spark SQL. Please see the below code for taking hours using the Date Part function.

**Select    datepart(hour,jou.creationTime)**

Any equivalent code in Spark SQL for the above line of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is and it is called `hour`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.hour

df.select(hour($"creationTime"))
```

To get string you can use `date_format`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.date_format

df.select(date_format($"creationTime", "HH"))
```